# Subscribers not showing in Supression List

Tags: import

I imported two subscribers to the Suppression List --> Omnio Test --> Omnio Test Suppression using Import Activity. The import activity was successful and I got an email saying 2 users were imported. When I searched for these users, I found these users and in the users attributes I found that they are part of the suppression list mentioned above but When I go to that list I do not see any subscribers over there. Is it a bug in Exact Target?

Comment: Are you asking about some specific project functionality which is not part of standard SFDC functionality?

Comment: No What I am saying is that when I am trying to import using import activity to Suppression List the import shows successful but I do not see the subscribers in the Suppression list which I imported